# The number of different (edge) clique covers of a clique

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, set-partition

### A simplified version

Given a complete graph $K_n$ on $[n]$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$, we consider all the possible edge clique covers of $K_n$.
Specifically, we aim to use a sequence of pairwise distinct node sets $\mathcal{V} = \{V_1, V_2, \ldots, V_k\}$ such that

1. Each node set is a subset of [n], i.e., $V_i \subseteq [n], \forall i$
2. Each node set is unique, i.e., $V_i \neq V_j, \forall i \neq j$
3. Each edge in $K_n$ is covered, i.e., $\exists V_i$ s.t. $\{ v_1, v_2 \} \subseteq V_i, \forall v_1, v_2 \in [n]$
4. The cover is minimum in that we cannot remove any node set while still covering all the edges in $K_n$, i.e., $\nexists \mathcal{V}' \subsetneq \mathcal{V}$ such that $\mathcal{V}'$ also covers all the edges in $K_n$

**Question:** How many different $\mathcal{V}$'s are there for a given $n$?

**Basic analysis:** Due to condition (4.), each $V_i$ should contain at least two elements and there must not be $V_j \subsetneq V_i$.

**A naive bound:** Let $c_n$ be the number of such $\mathcal{V}$'s.
Let $S(n, k)$ be the number of different ways to partition $[n]$ into $k$ disjoint non-empty subsets, i.e., the Stirling number of the second kind w.r.t. $n$ and $k$.
For each $k$-partition $V = \bigcup_{i = 1}^k V_i$ with $k \geq 3$, we can construct $\mathcal V = \{V_i \cup V_j \mid i \neq j \in [k]\}$ with $|\mathcal V| = \binom{k}{2}$.
For $k = 1, 2$, the above $\mathcal V$ would be simply $\mathcal V = \{[n]\}$.
Therefore, it is easy to see that
$c_n \geq 1 + \sum_{k = 3}^{n} S(n, k)$, which is related to the Bell number
$B(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^n S(n, k)$.

**Special cases:**
When $n = 3$, we have the following two cases and the bound is tight.

1. $(\{1, 2, 3\})$
2. $(\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\})$

---

**Below is my original question.**

Given a complete graph $K_n$ on $[n]$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$, we consider all the possible edge clique covers of $K_n$.
Specifically, we aim to use a sequence of pairwise distinct node sets $(V_1, V_2, \ldots, V_k)$ such that
(1) $V_i \subseteq [n], \forall i$,
(2) each edge in $K_n$ is covered, i.e., $\exists V_i$ s.t. $\{ v_1, v_2 \} \subseteq V_i, \forall v_1, v_2 \in [n]$, and
(3) each $V_i$ is effective, covering at least one edge that is not covered by the previous $V_j$'s with $j < i$, i.e., $\exists v_1, v_2 \in [n]$ s.t. $\min_j \{v_1, v_2\} \subseteq V_j = i, \forall i \in [k]$.
We can see that the cliques on $V_i$'s form an edge clique cover of $K_n$.

**Question**: What is the number of equivalent node sets (i.e., edge clique covers) for a given $n$?

We consider the order of node sets and define the equivalence from the perspective of edge partitions.
Let me show an example of *equivalent* node sets with $n = 3$.
In our definition, the following two sequences of node sets are equivalent:
$(\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\})$ and $(\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\})$.
This is because $\{1, 2\}$ covers the edge $(1, 2)$,
$\{1, 3\}$ covers the edge $(1, 3)$,
and after that, the only remaining edge to be covered is $(2, 3)$.
Hence, both $\{2, 3\}$ and $\{1, 2, 3\}$ are equally effective after $\{1, 2\}$ and $\{1, 3\}$,
and we see $(\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\})$ and $(\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\})$ as equivalent node sets.
Notably, we do not consider the order of how the edges are covered (see case 5 below).

I managed to enumerate all the possible cases for $n = 3$ as follows:

1. $(\{1, 2, 3\})$
2. $(\{1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3\})$
3. $(\{1, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\})$
4. $(\{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\})$
5. $(\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\})$ or $(\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\})$ or
   $(\{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 3\})$ or $(\{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\})$ or
   $(\{1, 3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\})$ or $(\{1, 3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3\})$ or
   $(\{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2\})$ or $(\{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\})$ or
   $(\{2, 3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\})$ or $(\{2, 3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3\})$ or
   $(\{2, 3\}, \{1, 3\}, \{1, 2\})$ or $(\{2, 3\}, \{1, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\})$

How can we find all the possible cases for larger $n$?
Even for $n = 4$, I can see the number of cases increases dramatically.
I am expecting at least a recursive algorithm via, e.g., induction.

Comment: It seems to me you should be including singleton sets according to your definition.

Comment: Singleton does not satisfy condition (3), ie, does not cover any new edge